# Why filters and filter-mappings (same with Servlets) are defined seperately?

Tags: spring, servlets, jakarta-ee, spring-security, servlet-filters

Does defining `filter` and `filter-mapping` seperately provide any benefit, while they could be combined in to one space? (Same is true with Servlets)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

By combining I mean something like below.

```
<superfilter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</superfilter>
```

Comment: yes the same filter can be used for different url patterns

Comment: then a `<url-patterns> <url-pattern> ...<\url-pattern>  <url-pattern> ...<\url-pattern>... <\url-patterns>` kind of collection could be more easy to manage...

Comment: what if you have 10 different urls you want to manage  ? you have to do it 10 times this way it resuable

Comment: how can you eloborate?

Comment: You don't need any of this anymore if you don't want.  What does it really matter?

Comment: what do you do with ongoing legacy apps... you can't kill them unless you think they will be born again in a new carnation. -1 is not justifiable.  Further more it's more of knowledge and to know the importance around why things are/were the way there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because by separating `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` , you can apply the same filter to different URL patterns.

From the comment, you propose why don't just combine them into a single `<filter>` likes:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <url-patterns>/foo<url-pattern>
    <url-patterns>/bar<url-pattern>
    <url-patterns>/baz<url-pattern>
</filter>
```

A filter and url mapping can have more configuration properties such as `<dispatcher>` (or may be more in the future specification) . Suppose all of above mapping has different  settings , your proposed solution may cause a 
  to have a large structure which look likes:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <url-patterns>
       <name>/foo</name>
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
       <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    </url-pattern>
    <url-patterns>
       <name>/foo</name>
       <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </url-pattern>
     <url-patterns>
       <name>/foo</name>
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </url-pattern>
</filter>
```

I think it is a matter of preference whether you like flatten or nested structure. I guess that Servlet Spec designer like flatten more and so go for the flatten choice.